# Problems installing Numpy 1.7 and Python-Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-12.04

I have python 2.7.3 installed on a Ubuntu 12.10 platform, and I attempted to install the Pandas library. The error message that I received stated that I need to have numpy version 1.7 or higher.

However, when I attempt to reinstall numpy (using pip install numpy), it always (re)installs the older default numpy 1.6.2, which is not compatible with Pandas. Is there a simple way to get around this? I can download and install numpy 1.7.2, but then import numpy will still look for 1.6 by default.

Comment: How do you install, do you use virtualenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer will assume nothing. Apparently, you database is out of date, so first check if that is true. I don't know how to do it with pip (and I have always had those kind of issues with it), so I always recommend doing it with apt (I have always done it that way). Keeping that in my mind, first check the version of the package you have available:

```
dpkg -l | grep numpy
```

After checking this, you should update your package index:

```
apt-get update
```

then your packages:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and finally check numpy's version again, the packages you need are python-numpy and python-pandas. If the package available doesn't suit your needs, go to the source page. I use Debian and it offers older packages AFAIK, so it should be fine. If that doesn't work, then it's easier to just install anaconda, which works great out-of-the-box.

Comment: I think I've resolved the numpy version problem, but now I'm getting the following error, when attempting to install pandas, which indicates that the wrong directory is being accessed for Python.h,     i.e. pandas/index.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you still sticking to pip? You have to be careful as to where programs get installed, depending on the python version you use. For example, python packages get installed in /usr/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages in general, but maybe you downloaded python from apt-get, then got pip, installed pandas in some version of python and afterwards upgraded python, but as apt-get didn't know about pandas, it only updated python, and then your old pandas was forgotten. I don't think these are issues that should stop you from coding, so I personally recommend trying anaconda or plain apt-get.

Comment: No, I used apt-get this time. I went back to square one and re-installed both Python and numpy again, and now the Pandas installation was successful. I'm still not sure what went wrong and why Pandas couldn't find the Python.h library, but in any case it seems to be working now. Thanks for your help.